# How to avoid overlapping requests when doing periodic requests with RxJava

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, reactivex

I would like to use RxJava (RxJava2 actually) to periodically send network (HTTP) requests. A first attempt would look more or less like this (adapted from this [source](http://blog.freeside.co/2015/01/29/simple-background-polling-with-rxjava/)):

```
Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
          .map(tick -> sendNetworkRequest())
```

This will call sendNetworkRequest every 5 seconds.

However if sendNetworkRequest() takes some time to complete (for example on a slow network, or if there are multiple retries..) the requests would overlap.

What I would like to do is to make sure there is an interval of 5 seconds *between* requests, i.e. from the end of the previous request to the start of the next one.

How can this be accomplished with RxJava?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `repeatWhen`

```
    Observable.fromCallable(sendNetworkRequest())
              .repeatWhen(observable -> observable.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I needed.